# ModelState.IsValid is true, but why?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following Login-Model:

```
public class LoginDto
{
    private const string EmailRegex = "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";

    public LoginDto(string email, string password)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = password;
    }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email darf nicht leer sein.")]
    [RegularExpression(EmailRegex)]

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Passwort darf nicht leer sein.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Which is passed into my Controller Method via `[FromBody]`.
I want to check, that both (Email and Password) are not empty by checking `ModelState.IsValid`:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin([FromBody] LoginDto loginData)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid) {
        return this.BadRequest(new Response(nameof(this.ModelState).ToCamelCase(), this.ModelState)                 {
            Status = ResponseStatus.Fail.ToString(),
            Code = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
            Error = new ErrorObject { Code = "InvalidModelState", Message = "Submitted object doesn't pass it's validation check.", Target = "payload" }
        }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately when I pass string.Empty as either Email or Password, the `ModelState.IsValid` is still `true`.

How can I achieve, that `ModelState.IsValid` is `false` when one of the properties is null or empty?

We're using .NET Core 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ (unrelated)

Comment: ^ [EmailAddressAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I do NOT need to validate manually by checking `this.ModelState.IsValid` anymore in .Net Core 3.0. The middleware is handling it when having the `[ApiController]` attribute on the controller.

> The [ApiController] attribute makes model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response. Consequently, the following code is unnecessary in an action method:
>
> if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
> return BadRequest(ModelState);
> }

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to add a `MinLength(1)` attribute.

Haven't tested it but should work i guess

Comment: For Reference: [MinLengthAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for this idea, unfortunately the ModelState is still valid

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  [BindRequired] to your model like this

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email darf nicht leer sein.")]
[BindRequired]
[RegularExpression(EmailRegex)]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Passwort darf nicht leer sein.")]
[BindRequired]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

You can read it more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#no-source-for-a-model-property)